# MLlib: How does RFormula.fit() work?

Tags: r, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

One possibility to create a model with Spark's `MLlib` is the `RFormula` module from `pyspark.ml.feature` as explained in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#rformula). However, I can't find any explanation how `fit` is actually implemented in this case. Does it use a squared loss function or something else? Where can I find this kind of information? The [source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/ml/feature.html#RFormula) is really hard to understand...

Comment: Refer this link : https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/05/generalized-linear-models-in-sparkr-and-r-formula-support-in-mllib.html

Comment: The fit() step determines the mapping of categorical feature values to vector indices in the output, so that the fitted RFormula can be used across different datasets.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to write a brief answer, I will accept it. Otherwise, I will write a short answer myself.

Comment: No problem. It helped right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Anoop Toffy, you can find a nice little tutorial [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/05/generalized-linear-models-in-sparkr-and-r-formula-support-in-mllib.html). To cite the tutorial:

> The `fit()` step determines the mapping of categorical feature values
>   to vector indices in the output, so that the fitted RFormula can be
>   used across different datasets.
>
> ```
> >>> formula = RFormula(formula="ArrDelay ~ DepDelay + Distance + aircraft_type")
> >>> formula.fit(training).transform(training).show()
> +--------------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+
> | aircraft_type| Distance| DepDelay| ArrDelay|            features| label|
> +--------------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+
> |       Balloon|       23|       18|       20| [0.0,0.0,23.0,18.0]|  20.0|
> |  Multi-Engine|      815|        2|       -2| [0.0,1.0,815.0,2.0]|  -2.0|
> | Single-Engine|      174|        0|        1| [1.0,0.0,174.0,0.0]|   1.0|
> +--------------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+
> ```